# Sencha Architect not creating getter for config variable

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I am using Sencha Architect 4.3 (Beta), sdk 7.4. Modern.
I have an Ext.form.Panel named TimesheetEntry written in the Architect.

Here is a fiddle of TimesheetEntry as generated by Sencha Architect and lightly modified to run in Fiddle
[TimesheetEntry](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3hnr)

You can see that adding config.fee_earner_user_id does not result in a getter.  The best I can do is to use win.getConfig('fee_earner_user_id');

My question is: how to specify in the Architect that fee_earner_user_id is a config property that should have a getter generated for it?

Comment: As far as I remember automatic getters will be created for config elements within `config: {}`, do you have `fee_earner_user_id` config there?

Comment: I have reworked my question and provided a fiddle to more clearly demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I don't use Architect, but if you add the following to the definition of `TimesheetEntry`, the getter will work: `config: {fee_earner_user_id: null},`.

Comment: Yes - that is my question - when using the architect how do I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you with that, adding the `config` part to your fiddle works, but I don't know how to make Architect do to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SA, enter fee_earner_user_id in the box where you would normally search for config options.  To the right of that box will be a button you can click to add it as a config option.
After it is added you can also change its type, i.e. string, object, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this.getView().getConfig('fee_earner_user_id') is the only way when using the Architect.